# `AccountInfo::realloc` is limited to 10kb per instruction, transaction or block?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

`AccountInfo::realloc` is limited to increasing an account's size by 10kb. Is this limitation per instruction, per transaction or per block?

It would be most optimal if the limitation were per instruction, as this would allow multiple instructions in a single transaction to increase the size. Though it wouldn't be a surprise if it was limited to 10kb per transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs and code are a little confusing around this point.  It's 10kB per account, per top-level instruction.

Comment: Great, so you can have multiple instructions that reallocate space in the same transaction

Comment: yep. same as you can have multiple instructions that _allocate_ new accounts in the same transaction